# "Era só jajão, quando tu dizias que me morres." Isto é gramatical?

Tags: gramática, conjugação-pronominal

A frase vem da canção [Jajão](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMgp904a3nc), também [aqui com letra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DdC6f8hBo6s), do cantor angolano [Master Jake](https://www.facebook.com/Master-Jake-358421524205601/timeline/).  [Jajão significa em Angola](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/jaj%C3%A3o) conversa para enganar. Ora Edno Pimentel, num artigo publicado em Maio passado na revista angolana [Nova Gazeta](http://novagazeta.co.ao/) e [reproduzido aqui no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/idioma/e-so-jajao-ela-nao-me-morre/3178), classifica este uso de "me morrer" como uma liberdade artística que ele, Edno Pimentel, professor, não se pode permitir. Diz ele:

> Se eu fosse cantor também tomaria a ousadia de inventar, criar novas palavras. Sorte têm eles, pois eu ainda não me posso dar ao luxo de "**morrer** alguém."

Ora, para mim a expressão "dizes que me morres" soa um pouco estranha, e possivelmente "morres" é ali usado num sentido não literal. Mas a construção "me morrer" ou "morrer-me" em si mesma não me parece estranha. E o que eu gostaria de saber é se "me-morrer" ou "morrer-me" é gramaticalmente correto ou meramente tolerável como liberdade artística.

Enviei esta dúvida ao Ciberdúvidas, e eles confirmaram a minha suspeita que a frase da canção é gramaticalmente correta. Dou pormenores na minha resposta. Infelizmente eles tiraram o artigo do Edno Pimentel da net!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mim a frase também não me soa nada bem, e é bem possível que esse seja um uso comum em Angola e que, como o Prof. Edno Pimentel diz, *me* é objeto direto nessa frase (ele fala em "morrer alguém", não "morrer a alguém"). Nesse caso não me parece gramatical.

Mas se for complemento indireto, é uma regência comum do verbo *morrer*, como nestas frases:

> O pássaro morreu-lhe nas mãos.
>   A minha mãe morreu-me no mês passado.

O significado é parecido com *morreu nas mãos dele* e simplesmente *morreu* (na segunda), mas é mais enfático; dá a ideia de que a morte teve um impacto emocional no sujeito.

A forma parece-me relativamente informal, mas, ainda assim, uma pesquisa no CETEMPúblico por `[lema="morrer\+.*" & func=".*DAT"] | ([func="DAT.*"] [lema="morrer"])` teve 86 resultados. Alguns exemplos:

> A senhora ajeita o cabelo, deixa o sorriso **morrer-lhe** na face e responde com ar severo:
>   Se ele **me morre** nas mãos com uma *overdose*, de quem é a responsabilidade?"
>   «Não, não podes imaginar, porque nunca **te morreu** um irmão."

Este tipo de contruções existem com outros verbos:

> A bolo desfez-se-lhe nas mãos.

E num uso mais popular:

> Não me desmaies agora!

Comment: Ora bem. Será que é objeto direto? Não há nada na frase que indique que o seja. a única coisa que eu acho estranha é o contexto, porque gramaticalmente não é diferente de "se ele me morre nas mãos..."

Comment: @Jacinto Acho que é esticar dizer que _me_ é indireto em "tu dizias que me morres, que me adoras", especialmente dado que _me_ é claramente direto na oração com _adorar_.

Comment: "Disseste que me telefonavas, que me avisavas:" o primeiro _me_ é indireto, o segundo é direto, nada de mais. Não tenho razão nenhuma para supôr um _me_ direto_ sem sentido ou sentido obscuro, quando o posso interpretar como indireto mais inteligível.

Comment: @Jacinto Point taken. Mas eu não sei quase nada sobre a variedade Angolana, e portanto não arrisco dizer que esse "me" é dativo. Mas há mais problemas. Em "tu dizias que me morres", não faço ideia que é que "morrer" significa. O uso do presente sugere que "morrer" significa algo com efeito *agora*. Ele não diz "tu dizias que havias de me morrer"... Portanto deve ser um uso de "morrer" não _standard_ e em que possivelmente o verbo é transitivo direto.

Comment: É verdade. Eu tento seguir o princípio de na dúvida, pro réu. Portanto acho que o Edno Pimentel é que tinha a obrigação de demonstrar que _morrer_ é ali transitivo, mas ele limita-se a insinuá-lo.

Answer (score 5):

O significado do verso terminado em "me morres" aqui é o mesmo da frase abaixo:

> Estavas mentindo quando tu dizias que por mim morrerias. <sub>Nota: futuro do pretérito condicional, urgh.</sub>

O significado aqui é de que a pessoa amada disse **estar disposta a morrer pelo cantor**, mas era mentira.

O verbo morrer, pelo pequeno uso, soa estranho. Ao substituir por outros verbos, vê-se a construção:

> Era só Jajão, / Tu dizias que me **AMAS**, que me adoras, baby!

---

Como está no artigo que o OP cita como fonte, este uso incomum trata-se de liberdade poética:

> **[Edno Pimentel]:** Se eu fosse cantor também tomaria a ousadia de inventar, criar novas palavras.[[ref]](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/idioma/e-so-jajao-ela-nao-me-morre/3178)

A conjugação proibida do verbo morrer é usada de propósito pelo cantor, e  então torna-se admissível. A licença poética também é regra gramatical, e dela advém boa parte da evolução da língua, quando o texto poético cai no gosto dos falantes e altera seus hábitos.[[citação, p86]](http://repositorio.unesp.br/bitstream/handle/11449/107018/ISSN1981-5794-2007-51-01-81-98.pdf?sequence=1)

Alguns verbos, por motivo de desuso, carecem de conjugação. Um bom exemplo é o verbo explodir, que até meados da segunda metade do século XX não tinha conjugação na primeira pessoa (não se admitia que alguem se explodisse, o que não é o caso hoje em dia, infelizmente).

> Contudo, esta perspetiva não era consensual, como bem documenta o registo que, passados alguns anos, Rebelo Gonçalves fez de expludo e expluda no seu Vocabulário da Língua Portuguesa, publicado em 1966; nesta obra, as referidas formas estão marcadas com um asterisco, de modo a indicar que se trata de formas teóricas, suscetíveis de uso efetivo e não reprovável.
>   https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/verbo-explodir/10082

Comment: Tou de acordo com a tua interpretação de "me morres". Não estou familiarizado com esse uso. Não sei se é comum em Angola. Também nunca tive dúvidas acerca da conjugação de "morrer"  simples: nem é assim tão pouco usado. A questão que continua por responder é se a conjugação pronominal de morrer, "tu morres-me" é correta.

Comment: Li agora a tua resposta com mais atenção, e há uma coisa de que discordo. *Amar* é transitivo, por isso se pode dizer _eu amo alguém, eu amo-te_. Mas isto não justifica que se possa fazer o mesmo com _morrer_, porque _morrer_ é intransitivo: não se pode dizer _eu morro alguém_. E o argumento do Edno, (não sei se leste o artigo dele, tem o link na pergunta) é que não é gramatical dizer-se _tu morres-me_.

Comment: @Jacinto A gramática admite ser quebrada em textos poéticos/artísticos/musicais. Não estaria correto dentro da norma culta em um texto sério usar esta forma, mas trata-se de música. Alterei a resposta para acomodar a liberdade poética.

Answer (score 5):

É verdade que, como diz Edno Pimentel, não se pode *morrer alguém*. Mas isto não impede que se possa dizer, por exemplo, *se me morres, não saberei o que fazer*. O Artefacto noutra das respostas apresenta vários destes usos de *morrer-me*. O *me* aqui significa que a morte da outra pessoa me afetaria. Chama-se a isto o [dativo de interesse](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/dativo-etico-e-de-posse-em-portugues/29880). Coloquei esta questão ao Ciberdúvidas, e eles confirmaram-me que o *me morres* na frase da canção pode ser entendido como dativo de interesse, e a frase é portanto gramaticalmente correta.

Eu escrevo na pergunta que acho a frase estranha. A razão é esta. O cantor diz *dizes que me morres*. O meu entendimento imediato disto é que a moça lhe disse *eu morro-te*. Ora uma coisa é eu dizer *não me morras; ai se me morres*, indicando o *me* que a morte da outra pessoa me abalaria. Outra coisa é eu dizer *eu morro-te*, indicando o *te* que a minha morte te abalará. É gramatical na mesma, mas é duma presunção desmedida. Deve ser por isso que se ouve *o pai dele morreu-lhe há dois dias; ele morreu-me nos braços*, mas não me lembro nunca de ouvir *eu morro-te* ou *casa comigo, ou eu morro-te* (ou então é só a mim que não dizem essas coisas).

Answer (score 4):

Em Angola ... A palavra "jajão" significa "simular/fingir" e/ou "Conversa para enganar
ou convencer. = LÁBIA, PALAVRÓRIO".

E ... Usa-se informalmente a palavra "morrer" para designar amor/paixão/atração.

Ex: Estou a morrer esta dama (caidinho por esta moça);
Ontem quando cheguei no boda, as damas todas me morreram (ontem quando cheguei na festa, as meninas não tiravam os olhos de mim/estavam caidinhas por mim);
Tu dizias que me morres (tu dizias que me amavas).

Comment: Muito interessante. Era esta a explicação que nos faltava.