# Pode servir como objeto indireto quem se importa com o acto?

Tags: pronomes-oblíquos, conjugação-pronominal

É possível indicar com o pronome pessoal átono (me, lhe, etc.) quem é que o acto beneficia ou prejudica? Sei que com certos verbos (*dar*, *fazer*) o pronome pessoal átono já tem mais-ou-menos este significado. Mas pode ser usado de forma mais geral?  Estou interessado em dois casos:

1. Quando o efeito na pessoa referida é um motivo para o acto. Por exemplo:

   > A criança apareceu com fome. A sua mãe cortou-**lhe** uma maçã.
   >
   > Estamos com calor! Quem pode abrir-**nos** uma janela?
2. Quando o efeito existe, mas não é motivo. Por exemplo:

   > Sujaste-**me** este lugar! *(Porque não o quero sujo.)*
   >
   > Eles vão a comer-**nos** toda a comida. *(E assim não vamos comer nada.)*
   >
   > Espero que o menino não **me** vá cortar o cabelo dele. *(Porque gosto do seu cabelo grande.*)
   >
   > Dá-**me** uma bolacha a ela, por favor. *(Quero que ela tome a bolacha.)*

Se não for possível na gramática formal, quero saber também se é usado de forma coloquial.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda com a gramática na minha pergunta!

Comment: Sempre às ordens.

Comment: Tens [nesta pergunta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1113/era-s%C3%B3-jaj%C3%A3o-quando-tu-dizias-que-me-morres-isto-%C3%A9-gramatical) outro exemplo do dativo de interesse: *não me morras*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim tudo isso é formalmente correto, e tem até um nome: [dativo de interesse](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/dativo-etico-e-de-posse-em-portugues/29880). O pronome oblíquo átono (me, te, lhe, etc.), formalmente objeto indireto do verbo, indica precisamente quem é beneficiado ou prejudicado pela ação.

Uma construção idêntica é o dativo de posse:

> (a) Sujaste-me a camisa. (Sujaste a minha camisa.)
>
> (b) Já me estragaste o dia. (Estragaste o meu dia.)
>
> (c) Morreu-lhe a mãe há três dias. (Morreu a mãe dele há três dias.)

Poder-se-ia argumentar que em todos estes casos a pessoa é também afetada pela ação, e que isso é até mais relevante do que a posse. Felizmente não temos que nos preocupar muito com isso, porque só o nome é que muda; a construção é a mesma.

Este dativo de interesse, sendo formalmente correto, é no entanto mais típico da linguagem informal.

Answer (score 3):

De facto, as tuas frases são todas (salvo uma) gramaticais, mas, com o Jacinto sugere, têm tipos distintos de clíticos. Vou desenvolver este ponto.

#### Dativo Ético

> (1) Espero que o menino não **me** vá cortar o cabelo dele.
>   (2) ??Dá-**me** uma bolacha a ela, por favor.

A frase 2 parece-me de gramaticalidade muito duvidosa. O clítico *me* ocorre num local onde seria de esperar o argumento recetor de *dar*, mas continuando a frase percebemos que é *a ela* que tem esse papel. Nota que se removermos o clítico, a frase seria agramatical (pelo menos em Portugal, no Brasil é comum):

> (2a) *Dá uma bolacha a ela, por favor.

Parece-me que *a ela* só poderia ocorrer naquela posição se estivesse a redobrar o clítico:

> (2b) Dá-lhe uma bolacha a ela.

Mas adiante. Em (1) temos o *dativo ético*. Mateus *et al.* (2003: 840) descrevem-no como designando «o locutor, manifestando o seu interesse na realização da situação expressa pela frase». Segundo as autoras, ocorre tipicamente na primeira pessoa do singular, embora admitam que marginalmente possa ocorrer na primeira do plural. Miguel Duarte (2010: 394) admite também a segunda pessoa, como neste exemplo que dá:

> (3) No Inverno, o vento sopra-*te* cá com uma força!

Segundo o autor, estes dativos «estabelecem uma relação entre a situação e um dos participantes no discurso e que remetem para um ouvinte real ou hipotético, ocorrendo tipicamente em frases avaliativas ou imperativas».

Uma propriedade que os permite destinguir dos outros dativos que referirei é o facto de não poderem ser realizados sob a forma de sintagma preposicional; em particular, não podem ocorrer em contextos de redobro de clítico:

> (4) *Espero que o menino não **me** vá cortar o cabelo dele **a mim**.

#### Dativo Benefativo

> (5) A criança apareceu com fome. A sua mãe cortou-lhe uma maçã.
>   (6) Estamos com calor! Quem pode abrir-nos uma janela?

Neste caso, estamos perante *dativos benefativos*, os quais designam a entidade beneficiada (ou prejudicada). Segundo Miguel (2010: 390), podem realizar-se como sintagma preposicional introduzido por *a* e, em alguns contextos, com *para*. É permitido o redobro de clítico («cortou-lhe uma maçã a ele», «abriu-nos uma janela a nós»).

#### Dativo de Posse

> (7) Sujaste-**me** este lugar!<sup>1</sup>
>   (8) Eles vão a comer-**nos** toda a comida.

Aqui temos um dativo possessivo, o qual designa posse em sentido estrito. Sintaticamente, é muito semelhante ao dativo benefativo, mas pode co-ocorrer com mais tipos de verbos. Miguel (2010: 391) dá exemplos de frases ambíguas entre uma leitura possessiva e benefativa. Outra diferença é que o dativo de posse, quando realizado como sintagma preposicional, não pode ser encabeçado por *para*, apenas por *por* ou *de*. O redobro de clítico também é permitido: «vão comer-nos toda a nossa comida».

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Como o Jacinto menciona nos comentários, parece ser também possível uma interpretação de *me* como dativo ético.</sub>

<sub>Maria Mateus *et al.*, 2003. *Gramática da Língua Portuguesa* (6ª edição, Lisboa: Editorial Caminho)</sub>
<sub>Matilde Miguel, Anabela Gonçalves e Inês Duarte, Inês. Dativos não Argumentais em Português. In *Actas do XXV1 Encontro Nacional da Associação Portuguesa de Linguística*, 388-400. Lisboa: APL. [Disponível online](http://www.apl.org.pt/docs/26-textos-seleccionados/Miguel_Goncalves_Duarte.pdf).</sub>

Comment: Revê-me lá a tua frase inicial. Algumas das distinções que tu fazes são demasiado subtis para mim. Não faço distinção entre *sujaste-me este lugar* e *abriste-me uma janela*. Também não gosto muito de *dá-me uma bolacha a ela*, mas daí a ser agramatical. Não me parece que *dá uma bolacha a ela* seja agramatical.

Comment: @Jacinto Tens razão, o "sujaste-me" é de posse. Corrigi isso na resposta, mas não agrupei com "abre-nos", embora não tenha certeza de que esse caso é benefativo ("cortou-lhe uma maçã" parece um caso bem mais fácil). A diferença entre benefativo e de posse é de facto subtil (a gramática da irmandade nem sequer faz a distinção e fala apenas de dativo de posse). Vê também o artigo cujo link está na resposta -- tem exemplos de frases ambíguas. Quando a _dá uma bolacha a ela_ ser gramatical... Discordo. Teria de ser _dá-lhe uma  bolacha_. Vou tentar arranjar citações.

Comment: Vê-me mesmo a primeira frase: acho que falta lá qualquer coisa. *Sujaste-me o lugar* parece-me que pode ser tudo: se eu me ia lá sentar, prejudicaste-me (benefativo) e poder-se-ia dizer também *sujaste o meu lugar*; se o lugar não me pertence de modo algum, provavelmente ético; se eu o tivesse reservado para um amigo meu, não me parece que seja posse, mas é benefativo. Ético puro é coisa como *olha-me para aquilo!*. E se houver um ele e uma ela,  *dá uma bolacha a ela* resolve a ambiguidade do *lhe*.

Comment: @Jacinto Qual primeira frase? «De facto, são todas salvo uma gramaticais, mas, com o Jacinto sugere, as tuas frases têm tipos distintos de clíticos.»? À parte de a frase ficar mais clara com "as tuas frases" na primeira oração, não vejo o problema.

Comment: @Jacinto Dificilmente vejo "sujaste-me o lugar" como ético. Parece-me ter exatamente o mesmo significado que "sujaste-lhe o lugar", o que é um argumento suficiente para dizer que não é ético (clítico da 3a pessoa). Por exemplo, Mateus dá esta como agramatical: _Cala-lhe(s) essa boca, pois já não te pode(m) ouvir chorar!_ (comparando com  o bem formado _Cala-me essa boca, pois já não te posso ouvir chorar_); teria de ser reformulada como imperativo diferido, com o dativo sendo de posse e portanto com redobro possível: _Cala-lhe essa boca (a ele) pois já não o posso/o podemos ouvir chorar!_

Comment: Essa frase mesma. Só percebi agora. E se escrevesses «são todas, salvo uma, gramaticais»? Imagina nós dois sentados num autocarro, e tu sujas o lugar ao lado. Nenhum de nós o ia utilizar, nem reservar para ninguém. Então eu diria, «sujaste-me esse lugar», como poderia dizer, «olha-me só para esse lugar todo sujo!»

Comment: @Jacinto Editei então a resposta. "Dei a ela" parece ser comum no Brasil, como diz [aqui no Ciberduvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/dizer-lhe-ou-dizer-a-ele/3976). A gramática da Gulbenkian diz a mesma coisa no capítulo sobre o Brasil, inclusive que _lhe_ é mais usado como acusativo no lugar de _o_ / _a_. Mais uma vez, falta de Malhação na juventude.